# Returning a single array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am struggling to understand how to return a single array from a function that calls another function several times. Currently, the console.log in the code below outputs a growing array each time the scrapingfunction runs.

The final last time that the scrapingfunction runs is actually what I want, but I want to find a way to return a single array at the end of the hello function so that I can drop each object into my database. I'm guessing this is just not me understanding javascript well enough yet.

```
const hello = async () => {
      //[launch puppeteer and navigate to page I want to scrape]
      await scrapingfunction(page)
      //[navigate to the next page I want to scrape]
      await scrapingfunction(page)
      //[navigate to the next page I want to scrape]
      await scrapingfunction(page)
    }

const scrapingfunction = async (page) => {
    const html = await page.content()
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    const data = $('.element').map((index, element)=>{   
        const dateElement = $(element).find('.sub-selement')
        const date = dateElement.text()
        return {date}
  }).get()
  console.log(data)
}


hello();
```

Comment: I removed the `puppeteer` tag since your question is about using async/await, not anything specific to puppeteer.

Comment: How did you managed to insert your data in DB? One array by one, or did u managed to make some method that merges all arrays objects into one single array? I'm facing similar issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you've encountered is that `Promises` (which is what `async/await` uses *"under the covers"*) cannot return values *outside the Promise chain*.

Think of it this way.

You ask me to write a StackOverflow article for you and *immediately* demand the result of that task, without waiting for me to finish it.

When you set me the task, I haven't yet completed it, so I cannot provide a response.

You will need to restructure your request to return values from your `await`s which can then be operated upon by the surrounding `async` function, such as:

```
# Assume doubleValue() takes some unknown time to return a result, like
# waiting for the result of an HTTP query.

const doubleValue = async (val) => return val * 2

const run = async () => {
  const result = []
  result.push(await doubleValue(2))
  result.push(await doubleValue(4))
  result.push(await doubleValue(8))
  console.log(result)
}
```

which will print `[4, 8, 16]` to the console.

You might think you could return the result from `run()` and print it to the console as in:

```
const run = async () => {
  const result = []
  result.push(await doubleValue(2))
  result.push(await doubleValue(4))
  result.push(await doubleValue(8))
  return result
}
console.log(run())
```

But since Node has no idea when `run()` has everything it needs to create a result, `console.log` will not print anything. (That's not expressly true since an `async` function returns a `Promise`, but the explanation works for this example.)

The rule is that you can `await` the result of other functions from within a function marked as `async`, but you cannot return any useful result to its surrounding context.

Since an `async` function does return a `Promise`, you could:

```
run().then(result => console.log(result))
```

But note that the result never leaves the `Promise` chain.

Comment: thank you very much, this is very helpful. I solved it by sending the data to my db each time scrapingfunction finishes, and then clearing the array, but your recommended solution might be a bit leaner since it would be nice to send it all in one batch.